How to do an incremental migration from a multirepo to a monorepo with yarn workspaces?
I have a multirepo project. It has an "app" repository that has multiple dependencies. These other dependencies have dependencies themselves.
I would like to migrate from a multirepo to a monorepo setup and I saw that yarn workspaces offer the architecture I would like to achieve (a real world example that I found is the jest repository which defines workspaces in its package.json file)
The specific problem I encounter is that I haven't found a way to perform an incremental migration to workspaces.
e.g
// app repository package.json

"workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
],
"dependencies": {
    dependency-a: "workspace:packages/dependency-a"
    dependency-b: 1.2.3

    // ...other dependencies
}

Under the packages folder I have migrated dependency-a. Ideally, I want to see that dependency-a no longer exists in the node_modules and instead only exists under thepackages folder.
The problem is the following:
dependency-a is also an internal dependency of dependency-b and dependency-b is used in various other modules. I think I am supposed to migrate dependency-b to a workspace as well, but since other modules link to it, it will continue to exist as a node module inside app until I have migrated everything (that is: dependency-b and all the modules that also list it).
Of course this creates a chain reaction. If migrating a module to a workspace means I also have to migrate its internal modules (that I wrote) to workspaces, there is no way to achieve an incremental migration, my only option is to migrate everything at once.
Am I understanding it correctly? Is there a resource / guide I can follow?

You should list your desired structure with a tree tool. That will help to provide an answer. In general you list all your workspaces as siblings of each other and yarn creates the necessary symlinks and installations appropriately. Also, what version of yarn?

@morganney 1.22.22. I would like to avoid to list all the workspaces as sibliings since this defeats the purpose of an incremental migration.
